# Multiple values ​that meet the conditions in the mongodb query list

Tags: mongodb, list

If I have the following datas:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f83f0b56cb4211529e890"),
    "fruit" : [ 
        {
            "fruit_id" : "a123",
            "fruit_color" : "red"
        }
    ]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8facc77a3e792210ba867f"),
    "fruit" : [ 
        {
            "fruit_id" : "b456",
            "fruit_color" : "red"
        }, 
        {
            "fruit_id" : "a998",
            "fruit_color" : "green"
        }
    ]
}
```

**How I use mongodb commands get this data:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8facc77a3e792210ba867f"),
    "fruit" : [ 
        {
            "fruit_id" : "b456",
            "fruit_color" : "red"
        }, 
        {
            "fruit_id" : "a998",
            "fruit_color" : "green"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need the data under the fruit to have red, green,
if data only have red, I don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, If you need to Fetch Two Data Red & Green Both Then Try This,

MongoDb Query [ $and, $elemMatch ] Both you can use it.

```
db.getCollection('Test').find({
   $and:[
        {"fruit.fruit_color":"red"},
        {"fruit.fruit_color":"green"}
   ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `$and` in query

```
db.collection.find({$and:[{"fruit.fruit_color":"red"},{"fruit.fruit_color":"green"}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
db.collection.find({fruit:{$elemMatch:{fruit_color:"red" , fruit_color:"green"}}})
```

Comment: I use this way, but get "Fetched 0 record(s)".